# Device installation forbidden by system policy

Tags: windows-7, installation, group-policy

I just bought a Logitech G500 mouse, but Windows 7 will not let me install it.  I get this error:

> Installation prevented by policy

[image]

When I try to update the driver through the device manager, I get this:

[image]

I have absolutely no clue what is going on here.  I have never ever tweaked any system policies.  I am an administrator and I have UAC turned completely off.

I am able to install other USB Devices such as flash drives and other mice.  I am an advanced user and am extremely comfortable using any command line or mucking about the registry.

Comment: Are you on a domain?

Comment: What does `GPResult` tell you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is your PC, or has your PC ever been on a domain at all, e.g. added to a server domain like in a workplace etc?

If not, try going to *Start > Run*, type in `gpedit.msc` and press OK. Go to *Computer Configuration > Administrative templates > System > Device Installation > Device Installation Restrictions*.

In here are loads of different settings which apply to installation of new devices, make sure they are all set to "not configured" apart from the very first one which says "Allow administrators to override restrictions" etc.

Another thing: Go to *Start > Run*, type in `rsop.msc` and post on here what policies are being applied.

Also post the result of this: Go to *Start > Run*, type in `cmd`, into cmd type `SET`, press enter and post whatever `USERDOMAIN=` is.

Comment: wow wow. great. Thanks for helping me. 
I was thinking my new device is  fully dead. But there was  policy issue of installation

Answer (score 6):

In my case the group policy was not configured, while the resultant policy device install restriction was enabled, didn't find anywhere to remove this restriction, then i found this registry key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions
Removing keys with restrictions from there solved my problem
http://amir-shenodua.blogspot.ie/2017/01/setup-blocked-by-group-policy.html

Comment: adding to it. You need not delete the restriction, just rename the folder on the left side under DeviceInstall to something else like Restrictions -> Restrictions-test

Comment: Nothing else worked for me, only this, thanks!