# Bluetooth audio devices "Setup blocked by group policy"

Tags: audio, bluetooth, group-policy

All of a sudden, I'm having issues with Bluetooth audio devices. All my previously connected audio devices now have a note "Setup blocked by group policy."

I've tried deleting registry keys as described in the article link in this answer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bluetooth-setup-blocked-by-group-policy/cb07c2f6-3f39-495b-8399-66a4f8f90da8

The following provided no solution either: [Device installation forbidden by system policy](https://superuser.com/questions/382896/device-installation-forbidden-by-system-policy/1164928#1164928)

**This is my personal system and has never been attached to a domain.**

Nothing is listed under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions

**Windows Info**

- Edition: Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 20H2
- Installed on: 3/‎13/‎2021
- OS build: 19042.1165
- Experience:  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0

[image: this is a image description]

It does not appear to be the driver, but I did uninstall/reinstall one of the devices. I have not tried a new profile.  Here are some additional screenshots that might be helpful.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the driver? or a different Windows User Profile before changing the registry?

Comment: Does this computer belong to a company or is it managed by a company?

Comment: While you are providing the other required information to answer your question.  Please also provide a screenshot of Settings -> Account -> Access work or school

Comment: Have you installed any security or privacy tools, or made changes to their settings, lately? Some of those tools use Registry Group Policy settings to lock down a PC.

Comment: You can try enabling `Optional diagnostic data` to see if it makes any difference.  However, in my research,  it sounds like you have a group policy that is preventing the setup for the device(s) from being executed.  What is the value of `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Don’t run specified Windows applications`?

Answer (score 1):

It ultimately ended up being a driver issues. Digging through the Device Manager I found that a Bluetooth Stereo device was showing with an exclamation point. Removing the device & drivers, reinstalling, etc. ended up solving the issues. Feels like the Group Policy problem as a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

The device must be uninstalled from the device manager and the subdirectory mentioned in the screenshot if none of the above works. This work probably would require multiple times for any subdriver such as mono, handsfree, etc. You can connect again once any drivers for that device have disappeared from your computer. (I have tested this procedure thoroughly)

setup blocked by group policy
[image]